# How to read from one sheet and print to another sheet in VBA

Tags: vba

I have two sheets, Sheet1 and Sheet2.

Sheet1 looks like this:

| Inputs | X if selected |
| --- | --- |
| A | X |
| B |  |
| C | X |

I want the code to print this in Sheet 2, starting in a specific cell (for example, B2):
|Outputs|
|-------|
|A      |
|C      |

How do I do this efficiently? I was going to write the following code, but realized it would take too long to do it for each individual input:

```
lrow=2

For i=1 
If Cells(2, 2) = "x" Then
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(lrow, 2) = "A"
    lrow = lrow + 1
End If
Next i

For j=1
If Cells(3, 2) = "x" Then
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(lrow, 2) = "B"
    lrow = lrow + 1
End If
Next k
```

etc.

Comment: Maybe the [FILTER](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759) function is sufficient for this

Comment: @Storax unfortunately I have to write a code for it, this is only a part of the overall goal

Comment: This sounds a little bit weird. Then I would wirte a code like `Range("A1").formula = "=FILTER(....)"`. Is this homework? [Here](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-copy/) you find further examples resp. code for copying data.

Answer (score 0):

You also can do it using Advanced Filter.

In sheet1 you have your information in columns A and B
You also have filter criteria, column D that is telling to filter items that have 'X' in column2.

In sheet2 you can specify the names of the columns to be shown. If you don't it will show all columns.

[image]

```
Sub advFilter()
    ' Source informtion
    Dim srcRng As Range: Set srcRng = Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    ' Criteria to filter the source range
    Dim crtRng As Range: Set crtRng = Sheet1.Range("D1").CurrentRegion
    
    ' Destination range
    Dim dstRng As Range: Set dstRng = Sheet2.Range("A1")
    
    ' Advanced filter
    srcRng.AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CriteriaRange:=crtRng, _
        CopyToRange:=dstRng, _
        Unique:=True
End Sub
```